# Rails 5 - Styling a collection in simple_form with item_wrapper_tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, collections, associations, simple-form

In my simple_form, I have a field that contains a collection as a series of checkboxes. It's very long and takes up a lot of space on the form.

I want to style the container the checkboxes are in with CSS so that it's limited to a 180px height and contained in a scrollable box. My code on the simple_form:

```
<th>Authors</th>
    <td><%= f.association :authors, as: :check_boxes, item_wrapper_tag: :div, item_label_class: 'h_180', label: false, collection: Author.order('name ASC') %></td>
```

I've wrapped the rails output in a div with `item_wrapper_tag: :div`. How do I style that div? Neither `item_label_class` nor `item_wrapper_class` is working.

Answer (score 1):

I have a checkbox selection in my app, but I implemented it somewhat differently:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:item_ids, Item.all.sort_by { |x| x.name }, :id, :name) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label class: "label-checkbox", style:"padding-right:5px" do >
            <%= b.check_box + " " + b.text + " "%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I think you could style the check box again the way the label is styled:

```
<%= (b.check_box class: "checkbox-class", style: "checkbox-style") + " " + b.text + " "%>
```

If you choose to implement the selection this way, make sure you allow your controller to receive `:item_ids` as a parameter.